# UI-Validate not allowing custom expressions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm on Angular 1.3.10 and Angular-UI-Validate is loaded correctly.

It gives errors for the standard `required`, but the error does not seem to have the `validate` property in the examples. It doesn't seem to see the `ui-validate` tag I put in the input, even using the example given by the author.

```
<input name="addStackInput" ui-validate=" {blacklist : 'notBlackListed($value)' } " ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$/" required ng-model="stackName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New stack name">
```

Script:

```
$scope.notBlackListed = function($value) {
            var blacklist = ['test','test1','test2'];
            return blacklist.indexOf($value) === -1;
}
```

Is there something wrong with the library? Did I make a silly mistake? Or is it something else completely?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- Have you include angular-ui js file in your index page?
- Have you include module in your app js file?

  var app = angular.module("plunker", ['ui.utils']);

if yes, do you put you $scope.notBlackListed inside your controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.notBlackListed = function($value) {
 var blacklist = ['test','test1','test2'];
     return blacklist.indexOf($value) === -1;
}; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had included the module the wrong way - I was declaring it in appController.js instead of app.js:

`angular.module('app',['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate','ngCookies','angular-loading-bar', 'ui.validate'])`